# How do I run Azure Functions from my domain

Tags: azure-functions, azure-custom-domain

So i can setup a custom domain to call an azure function, but this only allows me to call one azure function for the domain name.

How do i go about setting up a domain name path to call and azure function?

Comment: In order to configure custom-domain, we can delegate to Azure DNS Zone. 
Configure own domain with DNS Zone and there after we can configure with Function App.

NOTE: CNAME entry should be done from the DNS provider.
refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-custom-domain

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sample replication of setup custom domain to azure function App.

1. Setup and deploy a function App.
   [image]
   [image]

In order to configure custom-domain, we can delegate to Azure DNS Zone. Configure own domain with DNS Zone and there after we can configure with Function App.

[image]

NOTE: CNAME entry should be done from the DNS provider
upon adding CNAME entry on DNS side.  It will be able to browse the customdomain.com which points to function app.

Comment: As said in the OP that will only allow me to use one azure function per domain name, i want to use many, if figure out I can use azure front door or azure Api Gameway but both are expsive for what i want whicg is only mapping to the domain for now.